# How to remove interactive remote notification from notification center > iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, notificationcenter

I'm facing a problem trying to remove from Notification Center my interactive remote notification when tapped an option in Banner Mode (see image). Well, I can't find the way to do it (I will like to have the same behavior when you slide on blocked screen). I know I can accomplish this using Local Notification:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Does anyone knows how can I do it with interactive remote notifications?

[image]

Animated Gif taken from: https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 2):

Try removing all the notifications for that app from the notification center.

This may help you.

In Appdelegate inside handleActionWithIdentifier

Add the below code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Example

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication*) application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```